# Android Native view is not aligned properly when showing it using platform view in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-layout, flutter-layout, flutter-plugin

I am trying to create a wrapper plugin of android plugin for flutter usage.so i have created a flutter plugin and i am using platform view to show the native ui in android side and using AndroidView widget in flutter side. I have properly followed the flutter docs for the implementation.Noraml views like Textview and webview are working fine when returned from native side.

The UI from plugin is supposed to return camera stream inside yellow circle as shown in attached image but the stream alignment is not proper.

The same Plugin and its UI is working fine in any other android project.

```
class FlutterWebView internal constructor(
    context: Context,
    messenger: BinaryMessenger,
    id: Int,
    activity: Activity
) :
    PlatformView,KLivenessCallbacks, MethodCallHandler, AppCompatActivity() {
    val activity=activity
    val context=context
    private val kLivenessView: KLivenessView
    private  var methodChannel: MethodChannel
    override fun getView(): View {
        return kLivenessView//this is the object of UI class provided by plugin
    }

    init {
        
        kLivenessView = KLivenessView(context)
    }
}
```

This is the code snippet from UI class extending PlatformView in native android.[image]